# Kaltura Bulk Upload using RTMP link

Tags: migration, rtmp, kaltura

We have a number of videos on an Adobe server which uses rtmp to make the videos accessible.

Now we are migrating all the video content to a mediaspace using kaltura.

We are wondering if it is possible to use Bulk Upload CSV to directly upload RTMP media content.

Example file url for rtmp looks like this: rtmp://mywebspace.com/myvideo.flv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kaltura doesn't allow RTMP links for its CSV or XML bulk upload options but maybe you could do it through [RTMPT](http://www.onyxservers.com/kb/what-is-the-difference-between-rtmp-rtmpt-rtmpe-and-rtmpte-80.html?).

Here's the documentation about allowed protocols:

The comments at the top of the [sample bulk upload CSV](http://www.kaltura.com/content/docs/kaltura_batch_upload_falcon.zip) (Falcon version) state:

> Kaltura supports the following protocols: http; https; ftp.

It also doesn't seem possible to ingest via an RTMP link using their more robust XML bulk upload option.  According to the [XML schema](http://www.kaltura.com/api_v3/xsdDoc/index.php?type=bulkUploadXml.bulkUploadXML#), they allow ingestion via HTTP(S), FTP, SCP and SFTP as well as some other non-RTMP options.

I tested to make sure it wouldn't accept it and I got two validation errors in the XML, the first stating that the text didn't match the correct pattern (starting with HTTP(S)/(S)FTP/FCP) and the second that it's not a valid type 'T_url" value.

Here's the full list of "content resource" options from the XML schema page:

**serverFileContentResource** - Specifies that the location of content ingestion is on a Kaltura-hosted server. By default, this option is not available to Kaltura partners.

**urlContentResource** - Specifies that the location of content ingestion is a URL (http/ftp)

**sshUrlContentResource** - Specifies that the location of content ingestion is a URL (scp/sftp)

**remoteStorageContentResource** - Specifies that the location of content ingestion is a path within a remote storage defined in Kaltura. Using this option, only a link to the content location is set from the entry, without actually uploading content to Kaltura.

**entryContentResource** - Specifies that the source of content ingestion is the content of an existing Kaltura entry.

**assetContentResource** - Specifies that the source of content ingestion is a specific asset of an existing Kaltura entry.